# PHP- send array from one page to another and add some values into the same array in the new page

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a problem where i want to add some values into array AX.
At the page B, and array AX comes from registration.php where registration.php is a page to collect data such as name and address.

Data inserted is stored into AX, AX is sent to page B when user click proceed at the registration.php page.

At page B,there is a form to collect username and password. I want to add username and password into Array AX.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save your array into a `$_SESSION` variable (http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

You have to add `session_start();` at the beginning of your PHP code.

registration.php

```
$_SESSION['AX'] = $AX;
```

At page B you take AX from the session, you have to add `session_start()` at the beginning of the code again. Now, just add `username` and `password`

Page B

```
$AX = $_SESSION['AX'];
$AX['username'] = $Username;
$AX['password'] = $Password;
```

Comment: thanx a lot David. i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

After indenting and reading your question , i got what you need :D

what you need is to store data in a session for final process
so in the top of file that you collect first step data just use

```
session_start();
//Do your logic and save what you need to be exist in the next age inside session
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

and finally you can get what you saved using this code

```
session_start();
$user_name = $_SESSION['username'];
```

and don't forget to read about Sessions in php

That's All